# Show that $T(X) = (X_{(1)}, X_{(n)})$ is sufficient.

Tags: statistics, probability-distributions, statistical-inference

**Exercise:** Let $\phi$ be a positive (Borel) function on $\mathbb{R}$ such that $\int\limits_{a}^b\phi(x)dx < \infty$ for a pair $\theta = (a,b)$, with $-\infty<a<b<\infty$. Let $\Omega = \{\theta \in \mathbb{R^2}:a<b\}$. Define $$f(x|\theta) = c(\theta)\phi(x)\mathbb{1}{(a,b)},$$ with $c(\theta)$ such that $\int f(x|\theta)dx = 1$. Then $\{f(\cdot|\theta), \theta\in\Omega\}$ is called a truncation family. Suppose that $X_1,...,X_n \stackrel{iid}{\sim} f(\cdot|\theta)$. Let $X = (X_1,...,X_n)$. Show that $T(X) = (X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$ is a sufficient statistic.

**Question:** How do I show that $T(X)$ is a sufficient statistic?

I know that according to the mathematical definition $T(X)$ is sufficient if the distribution of $X$ given $T$ is known (does not depend on $\theta$). However, I think it's quite hard to find the conditional distribution and show that it's not dependent on $\theta$.

I also know that $T(X)$ is sufficient if no other statistic that can be calculated from the same sample provides more information regarding $\theta$. So I need to show that $T(X)$ gives us just as much about $\theta$ as $S(X) = (X_1,...,X_n)$ does. Intuitively I feel this can be done by looking at $f(x_1|\theta)$ and $f(x_2|\theta)$ and then inspecting what happens with $\mathbb{1}_{(a,b)}(x)$, but I'm not sure how.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try  [Neymann criterion](https://turing.une.edu.au/~stat354/notes/node56.html)

Comment: It's kind of "obvious". Given $X_{(1)} = \hat a$, $X_{(n)} = \hat b$, the (conditional) distribution of the sample $(X_1,\dots,X_n)$ is as follows: 
- for randomly chosen index $j$, $X_j = \hat a$; - for randomly chosen index $j\neq i$, $X_i = \hat b$; - the rest of the sample are iid with density $f(\cdot\mid \hat a, \hat b)$. So this conditional distribution is independent of $\theta$, as required. (The proof relies on the fact that given $X_1\in[s,t]$, its conditional density is $f(\cdot\mid s,t)$.)

Comment: @zhoraster Sorry, but it's not that obvious to me, obviously ;). You state given $X_{(1)} = \hat{a}$, $X_{(n)} = \hat{b}$. Why is this given?

Comment: I didn't say that this is given! I said something about the conditional distribution given this condition. And I agree, what I wrote isn't obvious, that's why I used quotes.

Comment: @zhoraster I think I might understand what you mean! If you look at the integral $\int\limits_{a}^{b}\phi(x)dx <\infty$ for a set $X = X_1,\ldots,X_n$, is this the same at looking at $\int\limits_{X_{(1)}}^{X_{(n)}}\phi(x)dx$ where $X_{(1)} = \min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$ and $X_{(n)}=\max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}$?

Comment: @zhoraster but even then; $c(\theta)$ will still depend on $\theta$ right? The parameter $\theta$ isn't given as $\theta = (\min\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\}, \max\{X_1,\ldots,X_n\})$.

Comment: @zhoraster Oh now I see... Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just use the Factorization Criteria, i.e., 
$$
\mathcal{L}(\theta ; x_1, ..., x_n) = c^n(\theta)I\{x_{(1)}\ge a\}I\{x_{(n)}\le b\}\prod_{i=1}^n\phi(x_i) ,
$$
thus $(x_{(1)}, x_{(n)}) $ is the sufficient statistic for $\theta = (a, b)$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer! I don't think I fully understand it though. Where did the indicator functions come from? Do we know that $X_1 \leq X_2 \leq\ldots X_n$?

Comment: 1. $X_{(1)} = \min \{ X_1,...,X_n\}$ and $X_{(n)} = \max \{X_1, ..., X_n\}$.
2. You support is $(a,b)$, thus $a \le X_i \le b$ for every $i$.

Comment: Thanks again! Just one more stupid question: why does this function does this function not depend on $\theta$? According to the factorisation theorem, $T$ is sufficient if for nonnegative borel functions $h$ and $g_{\theta}$ we have that $\frac{dP_{\theta}}{d\nu} = g_{\theta}(T(x))h(x)$, right? But right now our $f_X(x|\theta)$ is still a function that has $\theta$ in it.

Comment: Note that $g$ depends on $\theta$ only through the sufficient statistic. Anyway, maybe you should adopt the notion of (Fisher) information, i.e., $t(X)$ is sufficient statistic of $\theta$ if $\mathcal{I}(t(X)) = \mathcal{I}\{X_1,..., X_n\}$.

Comment: I'll try other ways yes, but I would really like to understand why $g$ does not depend on $\theta$, but only on the sufficient statistic. If you have that $T(X) = (X_{(1)},X_{(n)})$, you only know what the boundaries for $X$ are right? If you change the parameter $\theta$, then how will the statistic $T(X)$ account for this change?